# Wie heißt es richtig, Masterthesis oder Masterarbeit?

Tags: word-choice

Ich schreibe gerade an meiner deutschsprachigen Abschlussarbeit und wurde darauf angesprochen, warum auf meinem Titelblatt "Masterthesis" steht.

Sollte es richtig "Masterthesis" oder "Masterarbeit" heißen?

Comment: Schau in die Prüfungsordnung, oder guck was andere vor dir gemacht haben.

Comment: @starblue Das ist die einzig richtige Antwort. Die Bezeichnung für die Qualifikationsarbeit ist durch Universitätsgesetze und Studienordnungen vorgeschrieben. Wenn dort "Rübensalat" vorgeschrieben wird, muss auch "Rübensalat" auf dem Deckblatt stehen. Die Diskussion, ob die Bezeichnung sinnvoll ist, ist natürlich eine andere Sache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zugegeben, Masterthesis hatte ich noch nie gehört. Die Menge an Suchergebnissen fand ich dafür erschreckend hoch. Der Begriff wird sehr oft verwendet, durchaus abwechselnd mit Masterarbeit, aber auch ohne.

> Im Rahmen der Master Thesis soll der Student unter Beweis stellen, dass er sein theoretisches Wissen und die im Studium angeeigneten Kenntnisse auf ein konkretes und in der Regel an der Praxis orientiertes Problem anwenden und Erkenntnisse daraus ziehen kann. <sup>[bachelor-studium](http://www.bachelor-studium.net/master-thesis.html)</sup>
>
> Die Abschlussarbeit (Thesis) soll einen Unfang [sic] von mindestens 60 Seiten, höchstens aber 80 Seiten haben. <sup>[uni-giessen(PDF)](http://fss.plone.uni-giessen.de/fss/fbz/paemter/gwiss/dateien/kuehnl-luft/Handout/file/Handout%20zur%20Anmeldung%20Master-Thesis.pdf)</sup>
>
> Die Master Thesis ist die wissenschaftliche Arbeit, die Studierende verfassen müssen, um ihren zweiten Hochschulabschluss – den Master – zu erhalten. <sup>[mba-studium](http://www.mba-studium.net/content/view/545/311/)</sup>

Auffällig ist, dass das Wort niemals *Masterthesis* und selten *Master-Thesis* geschrieben wird, sondern stets *Master Thesis* oder nur *Thesis*. Wobei in meinen Augen es nur eine *richtige* Schreibweise geben dürfte und das ist *Masterthesis*.

Fangen wir mal an mit *Thesis*, was ja anscheinend gängig ist. *Thesis* gibt es in der deutschen Sprache, hat aber – [laut Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Thesis) – nicht viel mit Abschlussarbeit zu tun. Zumindest [Wikipedia weiß da mehr](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis), nennt so unter anderem *Bachelor-Thesis* und *Master-Thesis*. Wikipedia kennt wenigstens den Bindestrich und macht nicht so eine fiese Leerstelle (ist das eigentlich schon das Deppenleerzeichen?).

Wikipedia gibt aber auch indirekt die Antwort, woher dieses Wort kommt (zumindest ist so meine Schlussfolgerung) und man kann auch erahnen, warum es *Master Thesis* geschrieben wird. Es ist einfach die stupide Übersetzung aus dem Englischen.
Bleibt die Frage, warum ist das so? Schlechte Übersetzer? Also, nicht dass ich das Wort Thesis als falsch ansehe, das Wort existiert ja tatsächlich. Aber Abschlussarbeit, sprich Masterarbeit oder Bachelorarbeit, sind mit Sicherheit die zu bevorzugenden Wörter.

Comment: Es war nach der alten Rechtschreibung nicht unüblich englische Begriffe mit Leerzeichen zu schreiben. Diese Schreibung ist auch nach der Reform noch eine Alternativschreibweise, siehe z.B.: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hotdog (Wobei, wenn ich mich recht erinnere, war es früher:  Hot dog)

Comment: Den Ansatz, zwei englische Wörter nach deutschem Wortbildungsschema zusammen zu kleben, halte ich für ziemlich fragwürdig - das soll die (gar noch einzige?) richtige Schreibweise sein?

Comment: @guidot Es ist doch unerheblich, dass es einst englische Begriffe sind. Möchtest du die Wörter als fremdsprachlich kennzeichnen und getrennt schreiben, dann bitte "Master Thesis" in Anführungszeichen. Verwendest du sie aber in einem Fließtext als 'eingedeutschte' Begriffe, dann auch deutsche Regeln anwenden. Also ja, Masterthesis sollte die richtige Schreibweise sein.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a professor, and I have to say that I have *never* heard *Masterthesis* being used among students or faculty, or in the official university regulations; I've only seen or heard it called as *Masterarbeit*. (And, moreover, many people informally still call it a *Diplomarbeit*!)

Answer (score 7):

Zur Beantwortung der Frage ein Zitat aus dem Beschluss der Kultusministerkonferenz zu den [*"Ländergemeinsamen Strukturvorgaben gemäß § 9 Abs. 2 HRG für die Akkreditierung von Bachelor-und Masterstudiengängen"*](http://www.kmk.org/fileadmin/veroeffentlichungen_beschluesse/2003/2003_10_10-Laendergemeinsame-Strukturvorgaben.pdf) vom 10.10.2003:

> *"Zur Qualitätssicherung sehen Bachelor- ebenso wie Masterstudiengänge obligatorisch eine Abschlussarbeit (Bachelor-/**Masterarbeit**) vor, mit der die Fähigkeit nachgewiesen wird, innerhalb einer vorgegebenen Frist ein Problem aus dem jeweiligen Fach selbständig nach wissenschaftlichen Methoden zu bearbeiten."*

Answer (score 4):

Ich bin Professor und habe in Deutschland, UK und USA studiert und Abschlussarbeiten in Deutschland und UK geschrieben.
Meine Meinung dazu: Abschlussarbeit (Diplomarbeit) ist Deutsch; Master Thesis ist Englisch; Master Arbeit ist Denglisch.
Entweder sollte man im Deutschen bleiben, oder sollte in der gewünschten Landesprache. Zum Nachdenken: Wie übersetzt man eigentlich unseren Industrie- und Handwerksmeister ins Englische?

Comment: Allerdings heißt der Abschluss *Master*, so dass Abschlussarbeit ohne weitere Qualifikation ungenauer ist.

Comment: Ich möchte auch zu debenken geben, dass ich mehrer ehemalige Studenten kenne die nach ihrem Diplom noch den Master oben draufgesetzt haben und daher sich *Dipl. Ing. Max Mustermann M.Sc.*  nennen dürfen.

Answer (score 3):

Da es das Wort *Masterarbeit* im  [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masterarbeit) gibt, *Masterthesis* aber nicht , ist dieser Punkt schon mal einigermaßen geklärt.

Unabhängig davon, wird aber der Begriff *Thesis* gerne verwendet - meiner persönlichen Meinung zufolge, aber nur, weil manche denken, es klingt nach etwas Höherem als schnöde *Arbeit*...

Comment: Da muss ich dich korrigieren:http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masterthesis

Comment: @j0chn ich muss dabei sagen das ich für diesen Eintrag in gewissermaßen verantwortlich bin. Ich habe schlicht damals beim Duden eine Anfrage gestellt wie die das sehen und aufgrund dessen wude das in den Online Duden übernommen. Es wäre eigentlich mal interessant ob es das Wort mittlerweile auch in der Papierausgabe geschafft hat.